# from a PDF, extract highlights with page numbers from the command line

Tags: pdf

Is there a way to extract, from a PDF, the highlighted passages *with the corresponding page numbers* from the command line? I found two tools, but they do not exactly fit my needs: [pdf-highlights-extractor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfhex/) allows me to extract the highlighted passages with the page numbers, but it does not have a command line interface, only a graphical interface. And [DyAnnotationExtractor](https://github.com/dimi2/DyAnnotationExtractor) has a command line interface, but only gives me the highlighted passages, not the page numbers. Is there a tool that can do what I need? I am on Linux, by the way.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Hi . StackOverflow just isn't the forum this kind of "can you suggest some software?" question. Please take this question over to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ and I can offer some suggestions. Cheers!

Comment: @ZachYoung: Thank you for the reply! As suggested, [I took the question to softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/83422/from-a-pdf-extract-highlights-with-page-numbers-from-the-command-line-linux).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend usage of the nifty little Python library [pdfannots](https://github.com/0xabu/pdfannots), which has the very capability you are looking for.

```
$ pdfannots document.pdf
```

If combined with some other Bash commands, it can produce nicely formatted output. For example:

```
$ pdfannots document.pdf --no-condense | \
# Removing duplicate lines:
cat -n | sort -uk2 | sort -nk1 | cut -f2- | \
# Improving output formatting:
awk '{$1=$1};1' | sed 's/^\(> \)//g' | sed 's/* Page #/\n&/'
```